# Timeout exception when writing to a virtual COM

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I am trying to write to COM port using [.net sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.aspx)

I have no problem to write to a real COM, but when I try to write to a virtual COM I get a timeout exception

> Unhandled Exception: System.TimeoutException: The write timed out.
>      at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count
>   , Int32 timeout)
>      at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write(String text)
>      at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.WriteLine(String text)

I googled the issue, and found [this](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=155690). according to what is said there this is the issue:

> .net's write() function is using CreateFile and WriteFile Async like this :

```
CreateFile("\\\\.\\" + portName,
            NativeMethods.GENERIC_READ | NativeMethods.GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,    // comm devices must be opened w/exclusive-access
            IntPtr.Zero, // no security attributes
            UnsafeNativeMethods.OPEN_EXISTING, // comm devices must use OPEN_EXISTING
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
            IntPtr.Zero  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
            );

WriteFile(_handle, p + offset, count, IntPtr.Zero, overlapped);
```

when I used those I had NULL instead of the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPE

My question is, how can I overcome this issue? do I have to write my own code?

Comment: You don't need to use `CreateFile`, `SerialPort` class should be enough. Are you sure that the virtual port is open? And have you tried setting the [`SerialPort.WriteTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writetimeout.aspx) value to [`SerialPort.InfiniteTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.infinitetimeout.aspx)?

Comment: You get a TimeoutException when the driver can't get its transmit buffer emptied.  "Virtual COM" is hopelessly non-descriptive, but if somebody doesn't read what you write then a timeout is expected.

Comment: @HansPassant yes I did. but it didn't help.